# Facebook Fan Page, share button

Tags: facebook, button, share, facebook-page

I run a Facebook Fan Page which consists of posts directed straight from Twitter. How can I add a share button onto this posts on Facebook?

I'm not a computer know-all, so as much help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your posts came from a blog or website correct? If yes, then you can add the like button:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

If you is a new on fb social plugins, you can see what more you can do here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/